# Rewrite to https isn't working in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure new .htaccess file and everything seems to be working except HTTP redirect to HTTPS.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But it didn't work. Here's my full .htaccess file in it's current form.

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Add Caching
<FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|js|css)$">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>

# disable directory autoindexing
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
# https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to domain without www. for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Stop hotlinking.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %1#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#\1$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg)$ - [NC,F,L]

# Prevent viewing of htaccess file.
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

What am I missing?

Comment: By "not working", what do you mean exactly? Do you get a redirect loop? Nothing? Some other error? How is your SSL cert managed? Is this installed directly on your application server? Or are you using a SSL proxy, either by your host or some third party (eg. Cloudflare flexible SSL)? You have two lots of directives in your `.htaccess` file that are trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - only test one at once, otherwise it's going to be hard to debug.

Comment: It's just not redirecting to https. Ideally I want to redirect from www.domain to domain and http to https My cert is installed on the server for that domain. I tried commenting out things like hotlinking prevention, compression and such but it did not seem to help.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: "It's just not redirecting to https." - The thing is, you have multiple _conflicting_ directives in the `.htaccess` file you posted. It should be doing "something", whatever it's doing. So, you have to wonder whether `.htaccess` is even enabled? If you write garbage in the file do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Host/Server configuration try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
```